# When to redirect when to render

Tags: python, django, web-deployment

​**My scenario:**

​My app, handles signup at `/profile/signup/` using `SingupView(FormView)`.

```
class SignupView(FormView):

    template_name = "profile/signup.html"
    template_name_signup_confirmed = "profile/created.html"
    template_name_inactive = "profile/inactive.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):

        # Create and save inactive user
        self.created_user = self.create_user(form, commit=False)
        self.created_user.is_active = False
        self.created_user.save()

        # Create and save user's profile
        profile = self.create_profile(form)

        # Send registration email
        self.send_registration_email([self.created_user.email], registration_code=profile.registration_code)

        # Response
        return render_to_response(self.template_name_signup_confirmed, {'email': self.created_user.email})

    def form_invalid(self, form):
            if 'email' in form.errors and form.errors['email'].as_text() == \
                    '* An inactive user is registered with this email address.':
                return render_to_response(self.template_name_inactive, {'email': form.data["email"]})
            return render_to_response(self.template_name, self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

In `SingupView().form_valid(form)`  the User and his Profile are created, user is signed up, but inactive.

After that, in my case there is not success url to redirect, but render a new page, at the same address (`/profile/signup/`) with a new html saying "An email was sent at youremail@email.com, check and activate".

The same case when an inactive, registered user, tries to signup again, he will get a new page, rendered at the same adress `/profile/signup/` saying 'Your email youremail@email.com is already in our db but is not active.. .'

**My questions:**

- Can anyone explains if this is a good way to go, or I need to redirect to new urls, controlled by a new views?
- Is there any security risk by using render instead of redirect? Especially on user sign in/sign up?
- What is the difference when using redirect or render a new template at the same address? What is the best practice in Django?
- Is it ok, to display user's email, in the signup confirmation page and also in the alert page that says that user is registered but inactive in db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common pattern for this sort of behaviour is to use a redirect.

I would personally prefer that as it avoid the confuson of one view doing two things - one view displays and processes the form, the other displays a success message.

If the user manages to POST the form data a second time, what do you do?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

I am not aware of any greater security risk from using render rather than redirect (though someone with more expertise may know more than me about that).